# exception when trying to edit user role identity 2.x

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want to update user role. The user can have only one. While using the code below to change the user's current role I am getting an exception with the message:

> Invalid column name 'Description'.

I tried the async methods AddToRolesAsync and RemoveFromRolesAsync, but always the same exception.

```
private void setRoleForUser(AttributeRoleForUser attributeRoleForUser)
        {
            var user = _userManager.FindById((int)attributeRoleForUser.userId);
            var oldRoleId = user.Roles.SingleOrDefault().RoleId;
            var oldRoleName = _aspNetRolesService.Find(oldRoleId).Name;
            var newRoleName = _aspNetRolesService.Find(attributeRoleForUser.roleId).Name;

            if (oldRoleName != newRoleName)
            {
                _userManager.RemoveFromRole(user.Id, oldRoleName);
                _userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, newRoleName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is your table and model are in synced ? As the error suggest you are missing the column somewhere

Comment: I don't have a table with this column, that is what makes things ambiguous !

Comment: Can you show your role model ?

Comment: it is a simple ViewModel

Comment: `public class AttributeRoleForUser
        {
            public int? userId { get; set; }
            public int? roleId { get; set; }
            public List<SelectListItem> RoleLst { get; set; }

            public List<SelectListItem> UserLst { get; set; }

            public AttributeRoleForUser()
            {
                RoleLst = new List<SelectListItem>();
                UserLst = new List<SelectListItem>();
            }
        }`